# Perl Split on first occourence

Tags: perl, split

- Suppose string is:

  `ABC-Digest-M2-2.03-04.01.00.05`
- I want to split "**ABC-Digest-M2**" and "**2.03-04.01.00.05**" in two strings.
- First occurrence of - and digit combination. "**-\d**".
- How can I do this with one line of code ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use split with a lookahead assertion to do this without consuming the digit. e.g.

```
perl -MData::Dumper -e 'print Dumper(
    split /-(?=\d)/, "ABC-Digest-M2-2.03-04.01.00.05", 2
);'
$VAR1 = 'ABC-Digest-M2';
$VAR2 = '2.03-04.01.00.05';
```

Comment: oh my god.. how u did  that? I was wasting my time since morning but couldn't find out. Can u teach me how to make regex?

Answer (score 3):

Split on dash `-` followed by digit, and limit `split()` to max number of fields,

```
my $string = "ABC-Digest-M2-2.03-04.01.00.05";
my ($p1, $p2) = split /-(?=\d)/, $string, 2;
```